# Is creating bean for each of the config value from the file a good approach

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In one of our application development one of our team member keep insisting that the below approach is better:

1. Creating bean for each config value in the @Configuration class is easy scalable.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/conf/app.conf", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class AppConfig
{
    @Value("${snmp.disabled.mode:USER_MODE}")
    private String snmpCheckDisabledMode;

    @Bean
    public String snmpCheckDisabledMode() { return snmpCheckDisabledMode; }
}
```

```
@Component
public class SnmpManager
{
    @Autowired
    private String snmpCheckDisabledMode;


    function activateSnmpWalk(String curentMode)
    {
        if (!cusnmpCheckDisabledMode.equals(currentMode))
        {
            startSnmpWalk();
        }
    }
}
```

I mentioned to the team that either using @Value annotation or Environment is better to get the values in the @Component class.

I am not sure which is the right approach. Can some one give some idea.

Comment: Nowadays it is generally preferable to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to group all properties under one prefix and autowire that ConfigurationProperties class.

Comment: Using the Value annotation is ok too.if what is suggested is making a separate configuration for each entry, that seems a bit crazed. Sounds like your coworker needs to go lie down for a bit and lay off reading about SOLID design stuff.

Comment: Does your coworker wants these properties to be managed by spring beans. That is an unnecessary overload.

Comment: why on Earth would you want to create a Bean for every possible String you can parametrize using properties?